# How to set up a celery delayed task from django view using rabbitmq queue

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have to create a task in celery using the rabbitmq in a django project. Basically the project is need to send push notification. There is two option for the admin person to send the push notification

> 1) Send now: When they click the push notification send instantly
>
> 2) Send later: In this case admin set a date and time and i need to
>   send  the push notification on that date and time only.

My tasks.py is

```
from celery.task import task
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

#@task
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')))
def multiply(x, y):
    multiplication = x * y
    print('print me here')
    return multiplication
```

celery.py is

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
app = Celery('mazda')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


#s@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and i am caling the task from the view like `result = multiply.delay(3,5)`

When i am running the command `celery -A {myappname} worker -l info` i can see that the task is created on celery and one queue is additionally generating on rabbitmq queue also(Here i am not able to check the same task is created or not)

Now my issue is how can a call this task on the time and date the admin choose from the admin side. All the documenation is saying the delay function, bt nothing gives me the option for setting the exact delay for a task. Please help me on this.

settings.py file is

```
import os
#import djcelery
#djcelery.setup_loader()
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'bjn4ngz(mk*$*(z12jk+ztf4b*-p@b42l#)rind!cl)$%z49h^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mazda.apps.MazdaConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'push_notifications',
    'djcelery'
    #'djng',
]
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
        "GCM_API_KEY": "AIzaSyC4YNDJBVJK75QEVWuMKPXuTgiIEfa26Pw",
        "APNS_CERTIFICATE": "pushLatestPushFile.pem",
    #    "WNS_PACKAGE_SECURITY_ID": "",
    #    "WNS_SECRET_KEY": "",
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin123',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_URL = '/mazda/userlogin'

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply_async()` with `eta` parameter (eta must be a datetime object, specifying an exact date and time, including millisecond precision and timezone information):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
>>> multiply.apply_async((3, 5), eta=tomorrow)
```

More information in the celery docs [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown).

Comment: So in my view.py how can i call this? If i call result = multiply.apply_async(3,5, countdown=10) like this in my view.py, how can set the this to be work for after 10 second on my tasks.py?

Comment: the worker will delay until the time you set to be execute the task. @anoop